# Error cannot read property '1' of undefined al imprimir una matriz con un while

Tags: javascript

El problema sucede al momento en que imprimo la matriz se traba el código y no puede ingresar a mis otras opciones

```
case "2":             

    for (var i = 1; i < 16; i++) { 
                             
        for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) { 
            document.write("["+matriz[i][j]+"] "); 
        } 

    document.write("<br>");
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
error:Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Mi matriz está definida así:

```
   var matriz = new Array(15);

   for  (var i = 0;i<matriz.length;i++){
       matriz[i]= new Array(12);
   }
```

Código completo:

- https://code.sololearn.com/WWv2pmsd77w0

Comment: Falta un montón de código relevante, dónde está el `case 1:` para el `switch`. A el constructor `new Array` le debes de pasar como parámetros los elementos del nuevo array. Además no das un contexto, en que linea te da el error? Deberías editar la pregunta y ser más especifico.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, **¿qué contiene `daka`?** Si no tiene suficientes elementos no se definirá el índice `1`.

Comment: Jerwos, cuando hagas una edición a consecuencia de un comentario, deberías avisarlo en los comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta, discúlpeme soy nuevo en la comunidad

Comment: Hola de nuevo Jerwos. ¿Mi respuesta solucionó tu problema? ¿Tienes alguna duda más?

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que en tu código sólo haces `matriz[i]= new Array(12)` en la opción 1:

```
if(ciudad==01){
    for  (var i = 0;i<matriz.length;i++){
        matriz[i]= new Array(12);// Llenado de inventario (Productos) */
        /* ... */
```

Sin embargo en la opción 2 no lo haces, por lo que si vas a la opción 2 sin haber pasado por la 1, el contenido del segundo nivel no habrá sido definido.

Podrías definir inicialmente todos los valores de la siguiente manera:

```
var matriz = new Array(15);

for (let i = 0;i < matriz.length; i++) {
    matriz[i]= new Array(12);
    for (let j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
        matriz[i][j] = null;
    }
}
```

Pero lo más lógico es detectar previamente si ese índice ha sido generado o no para definir su contenido.